# Button icons lost after updating to Mavericks

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, icon

Since updating to Mavericks, the buttons on the Apple apps have all lost thier icons:

[image: Safari doesn't show any icons on the buttons]

Can anybody advise how I can restore them?

```
Macbook Pro
13-inch, Early 2011
Processor  2.7 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory  8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
Graphics  Intel HD Graphics 3000 512 MB
Software  OS X 10.9 (13A603)
```

Comment: Two questions. Did you photoshop the menu bar or install a tool that modified it? Does Safari and Mail have this problem if you create a new second account on your Mac and log in to that account?

Comment: I didn't Photoshop the menubar - as far as I'm aware I haven't installed anything other than the Evernote, and that was a while ago. When I sign in under a new user account, I can see the icons no problem.

Comment: The usual answer for weird behavior like this is to repair permissions on the main drive.  I don't use Mavericks yet, so I can't confirm this, but I assume that it's still in the Disk Utility app.

Comment: @Bobson - thanks for your suggestion. Repairing the permissions hasn't helped though :/

Comment: You might try Control-Clicking and selecting customize toolbar, then remove and put everything back in. There's a good chance that won't work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thanks Zoyt but it's not just Safari - It's all of the Apple apps. :/

Comment: Try also asking on Apple Support if you haven't already (requires Apple ID, which I assume you have). https://discussions.apple.com/index.jspa

Comment: Thanks - I haven't had any luck there either though :( https://discussions.apple.com/message/23954370#23954370

Answer (score 1):

Given that the issue is limited to your user account, I would assume the problem lies within your home directory. Per [this MacRumors thread](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1575747), have you tried deleting ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist? I can't replicate your issue, but I have deleted this file seemingly without untoward effect on my 10.9 system.

By way of further diagnostics, you might also try [Safe Booting](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1564?viewlocale=en_US) by holding the Shift key on startup and see if the problem still occurs.

Comment: I'd like to add that restarting with "reopen windows when logging back in" **unchecked** _may_ help.

Comment: Thanks @tullyhansen - I tried both of these but to no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing the user and system caches, including the font caches.
Corruption of caches can cause display problems.

Something like http://yasuapp.com or http://www.maintain.se/cocktail/index.php can clear the caches easily.

Comment: Thanks - I downloaded Yasu and ran the full clean. Still seeing the same issue :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a Time Machine backup, reinstalling OS X and then restoring from the same backup? It's unideal, I'll give you that. However, this is a surefire way that your problem will be repaired.